# Update cells from another sheet, based on the value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for an efficient method to loop through cells and update empty cells based on the cell value of an adjacent cell.

On sheet 1, column H has vehicle numbers (no empty cells) & column T has arrival times (some empty cells).

On sheet 2, column AB has vehicle numbers & column AH has arrival times.

I want my code to loop through all missing arrival times on sheet 1 to and update with the arrival time from sheet 2, if available.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just filter on all blank cells and then insert a vlookup function on visible cells? Also, you would probably do better to post some sort of start. Write a loop or something.

Comment: It occurred to me to insert a formula into the blank cells. I was wondering if there is a method that is more efficient.